# Cut text with CSS by width of its parent container

Tags: html, css, text

I have that text that currently surpasses the width of the fill (if the parent's width is 14% at most), so it goes out of the fill. I'd like to chop that text, relying on parent's width.

```
<div class="progress-fill">
  <div class="progress-text">Christmas is Coming Soon</div>
</div>
```

How to get this?

Comment: `.progress-fill { overflow: hidden; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either
`.progress-fill { overflow: hidden; }`

or ([CSS3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap))
`.progress-fill { word-wrap: break-word; }`